# Shell Script

Tags: shell, scripting

Please enlighten me. What does the following snippet of a shell script mean?

```
FNAME=Grapes.txt

touch Apple.txt
   ls Banana.txt | while read FNAME
   do
    /somePath/ftp_autojobs.sh someFolder/LG $FNAME Apple.txt
   done
```

**EDIT**: ftp_autojobs.sh transfers files to a server.

Content of ftp_autojobs.sh:

```
SO=`tput smso`
SE=`tput rmso`
RETURN="$SO RETURN $SE"

TEMP_FN=`mktemp -c -d . -p ftp`
TEMP_LOG=`mktemp -c -d . -p log`

echo open some.server.com>>$TEMP_FN
echo user user pass>>$TEMP_FN
echo cd \"$1\">>$TEMP_FN
echo binary>>$TEMP_FN

shift
until [ $# -eq 0 ]
do
   echo mput \"$1\">>$TEMP_FN
   shift
done

echo bye>>$TEMP_FN

ftp -vin < $TEMP_FN > $TEMP_LOG

FILE_COUNT=`grep "226 Transfer complete" $TEMP_LOG|eval wc -l|cut -d ' ' -f 1`

if [ $FILE_COUNT -eq 0 ]
then
   rm -f ftp_commands.txt 2>/dev/null
   rm -f ftp.log 2>/dev/null
   mv $TEMP_FN ftp_commands.txt
   mv $TEMP_LOG ftp.log
   cat ftp.log
   banner "WARNING" "FTP FAILED"
else
   rm -f $TEMP_FN
   rm -f $TEMP_LOG
   echo $FILE_COUNT Files sucessfully transferred.
fi
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be useful to know what ftp_autojobs.sh contains.

Comment: I suppose you changed all file names?

Comment: @Enty: Edited. It transfers files to a server. 

@Splattne: Doesn't matter I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In simple format....

SETS FNAME to Grapes.txt

creates Apple.txt

then does ftp_autojobs.sh someFolder /LG Grapes.txt Apple.txt

Done

Not much more than that....

Comment: How about this loop-

ls Banana.txt | while read FNAME?
And do..done? Thanks.

Comment: `ls Banana.txt` will output nothing if Banana.txt does not exist, and therefore `read FNAME` will exit with an error and `while` will not run the do/done loop. If Banana.txt does exist, the ls command will output "Banana.txt" which will be fed into `read FNAME` which will set FNAME to "Banana.txt" and return 0 which will trigger `while` to run the do/done block. This is basically a strange way to write the following if statement: `if [ -e Banana.txt ]; then /somePath/ftp_autojobs.sh someFolder/LG Banana.txt Apple.txt; fi`.

Answer (score 1):

- It updates the timestamp on Apple.txt (or creates it if it don't exist)
- If Banana.txt exists and is a file, the while loop will be run once with Banana.txt in place of $FNAME
- If Banana.txt exists and is a directory, for each item in Banana.txt/ the ftp_autojobs.sh statement will be run with the filename of the items in place of $FNAME

Answer (score 0):

My blind guess is that it is backing up some files to an FTP server. There are some "magic" things we can't know about that script. It seems that the "Apples.txt" file is some kind of log.

The biggest mystery are the content and parameters of the `ftp_autojob.sh` script. Maybe you could add some information tio your question.

Answer (score -1):

As an aside, I do not think that is as written as well as it could be, see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.60ls_.2A.mp3.60) for why.  Consider the following instead:

```
 while read FNAME
 do
    /somePath/ftp_autojobs.sh someFolder/LG "$FNAME" Apple.txt
 done < Banana.txt
```

Comment: But that's how it has been done for years.. Working fine.. We are converting this in Java..

Comment: This statement is not equivalent. It will read lines from Banana.txt and use them as FNAME in the loop. The original script pipes the output of `ls Banana.txt` (which will be "Banana.txt" if Banana.txt exists and empty if it does not) to the `while read` loop, turning it into basically an if statement, equivalent to `if [ -e Banana.txt ]; then ...; fi`.